# Not getting workflow version of the item (component) in core service

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am triggering a workflow on a component X by updating the component values.

In my C# External Activity class i am trying to get the changed value from the above component.Each time i am getting the old value. Workflow version of item is not coming in External Activity.

How can i get the workflow version of Component in External Activity C#.
Do i need to manually create the workflow version of component?

Reading of Data :

```
ComponentData component =  
(ComponentData)CoreServiceClient.Read(ActivityInstance.WorkItems[0].Subject.IdRef, new     
ReadOptions());
```

This is how i am reading the workflow component.

Publish the Page :

```
PublishItem publishItem = new PublishItem();
PublishInstructionData publishInstruction = new PublishInstructionData
{
    ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData()
    {
        IncludeChildPublications = false,
        IncludeWorkflow = true
    },
    RenderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData()
};
publishItem.Publish(CoreServiceClient, publishInstruction, new String[] { pageTCMUri }, new String[] { previewTarget }, PublishPriority.High);
```

Just now i checked that new value is getting published to staging as expected.But i want to  execute some logic on basis of changed value in component in External Activity.

Comment: There might be plenty of reasons for this to happen. Could you please post the code of your external activity?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Can you confirm that `component` variable has no changes?

Comment: component variable has no changes .

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the Component Approval Status doesn't match the Publication Target Approval Status. If your Activity is setting the Approval Status to the same Approval Status as the Publication Target make sure that you are finishing (Applying the Approval Status) before you publish

Answer (score 0):

According to: [this](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5CC5E3CF-E840-4E6E-9F90-1DB0C1CB3FCC&addHistory=true&query=automatic%2520activity%2520variables&scope=&tid=2ce9f2c5-cac0-40b0-bd21-7f7991fe3c35&filename=GUID-5CC5E3CF-E840-4E6E-9F90-1DB0C1CB3FCC.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5CC5E3CF-E840-4E6E-9F90-1DB0C1CB3FCC&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=automatic%2520activity%2520variables&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1396869841846&currentQuery=automatic%2520activity%2520variables&currentScope=)
There's no `ActivityInstance` variable predefined, so I assume you have created it yourself and it might be the case that it's not correct. Try using `CurrentActivityInstance` instead.

Try this:

```
(ComponentData)CoreServiceClient.Read(CurrentActivity.WorkItems[0].Subject.IdRef‌​, new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: This is what i have used ActivityInstance and it is a defind variable . I have not created it .     ActivityInstanceData currentactivity = (ActivityInstanceData)CoreServiceClient.Read(ActivityInstance.Id, new ReadOptions());
            ComponentData component = (ComponentData)CoreServiceClient.Read(currentactivity.WorkItems[0].Subject.IdRef, new ReadOptions());

Comment: Try this (see my update). Also, do you have just 1 component in the workflow?

Comment: Yes, i have only one component in workflow. In your line of code CurrentActivity is undefind.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly for your case, but for getting dynamic version you need specify UseDyncamicVersion condition. If I am not mistaken default behavior - load major version(DynamicVersionResolvingConditions.None).

```
 ComponentData component =  
            (ComponentData)CoreServiceClient.Read(ActivityInstance.WorkItems[0].Subject.IdRef,
     new ReadOptions()
                {
                  UseDynamicVersion = DynamicVersionResolvingConditions.CheckedOutByUser
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by using a different identity for your core service access than you are using to view the item in the GUI. The workflow version of an item is only displayed to the assignee that actually has the item in workflow.